# DISCORD.PY PYTHON - I want to make a function which sends a global message in the server when a user joins in the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pypi

I am trying to make a Discord BOT using Python. I am creating different kind of functions and now I want to create a function that lets the BOT to send a message in the general channel when someone joins the server

```
import discord
import random

from discord.ext import commands

token = 'BOT_TOKEN'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} is now ready')

@client.command(aliases = ['ask', 'chiedi'])
async def _ask(ctx, *, question):
    file_object = open("quotes.txt")
    quotes = file_object.readlines()
    file_object.close()

    rnd = random.choice(quotes)
    await ctx.send(rnd)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    content = message.content
    log = '{}: {}'.format(author, content)
    with open("logs.txt", "a+") as my_file:
        my_file.write(log + "\n")
        my_file.close()

'''
func print_msg
    once the user joins the server
    print message to greet him

'''

client.run(token)
```

I expect the output to be something like "Username has joined our server! Welcome."

Comment: Please be more specific and provide code snippets of the work done on your end for problem scoping.

Comment: I edited your post; *Do not show your bot's token to anyone*. Someone who have your bot's token can have access to your entire bot.

Comment: I know, it's a different token

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using version `1.3.0a`... (or somewhere close)

You can basically follow the template that they have given on [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#basic-concepts). There is one for [`on_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready) and another for [`on_message(message)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message). 
Just find the respective event that you need in the docs, what you probably want is [`on_member_join(member)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join),
 like so:

```
# ...
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.guild.text_channels[0].send("A message sent to the first channel because a member joined!")
# ...
```

Comment: /Python Bot/domenico.py:35: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
  member.guild.text_channels[0].send("Test")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: @LorenzoOrlando I forgotten to add an `await` behind... Edited my answer;

Comment: Thank you sir! Now it's working. But what if I want to do the same thing when someone leaves or is kicked? Should I just change it in to on_member_leave?

Comment: @LorenzoOrlando The events and their descriptions and interfaces are described in the [Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference)